# C++ Functors, how to define ! operator?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

**Note: I'm working with C++11**

I wrote the following functor:

```
class Between {
private:
    int min;
    int max;
public:
    Between(int min, int max) :
            min(min), max(max) {}

    bool operator()(int val) const {
        return min <= val && val <= max;
    }
};
```

So if I need to check if every member in the Matrix is `>num` I can call my function which is called filter like this:

```
Matrix Matrix::operator>(int num) const {
return filter(*this,Between(num+1,INT_MAX));
```

}

But what if I need to check if every member is not equal to num?
I can't write something like this:

```
return filter(*this,!Between(num,num));
```

Comment: is my question clear?

Comment: Yes, however the usage has some details that are unnecessary. Remove both the `Matrix` class, and the `filter` function. Just use `Between` with some standard types, and algorithms.

Comment: @cigien I though about that, but yet the solution may be related to them (I am thinking of something close)

Comment: Then you should definitely figure that out. If it's not related, then a simpler usage would be easier to understand. If it *is* related, then the question is not answerable without more details about `Matrix`, and `filter`.

Comment: I solved this by adding additional parameter to my function filter for that specific case. but still believe this is "not smart" solution

Comment: Then you need to provide the implementation of `filter`. In fact, you need to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You might be looking for [`std::not1`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not1). As in `return filter(*this,std::not1(Between(num,num)));`